# cbdocloader is not existed on my couchbase bin file

Tags: couchbase

I wanna use the cbdocloader tool. According to this official page http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/CLI/cbdocloader_tool.html it should be existed on the bin folder in couchbase folder. However, I didn't find it.

I tried to search for installation but it seems that It should have been installed with the couchbase itself, right?

how can I install it please?

Comment: Which version of Couchbase are you using, and which platform are you running?

Comment: @mrkwse version 3 on windows 64 bit windows 7